# Using a Google Apps API key with Distance Matrix

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) and the documentation tells me I need an API key (but I can use it without one.)  I'd like to be able to monitor use but I'm stumped as to how to set it up.

I have a valid browser application API key from the Google Developers Console, it's new so I'm assuming it's a version 3 key.

I have added valid referers in the console

I have `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>` on my page

I'm using code like this

```
function callback(response, status) {
    if (status!==google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        _googleError('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;

        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    $("#calcDistance").val(results[j].distance.text);
               //Other stuff that works here
            }
        }
    }
}

function calculateDistances(start, end) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [start],
            destinations: [end],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
}
```

As it is things work just fine.  When I try to add the key in things go south.  I've tried

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&v=3.exp"></script>`

and

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}"></script>`

with no luck.  When I do either of those I get an error about invalid URL, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456714/google-distance-matrix-api-v3-showing-error).

I've also tried adding `key: {MY_KEY},` into `calculateDistances()` - no luck with that either.

Am I missing something obvious?  (I feel like I am)

**UPDATE:**

@Dr.Molle's answer got me what I was looking for.  I turned on "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" and changed `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>` to `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_KEY}&v=3.exp"></script>`  Now I can view activity in the Developer Console like I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the key when loading the maps-Javascript-API you must enable the API "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" inside the console.

The linked documentation is for the Webservice, the key-related part of this documentation is irrelevant when you request the DistanceMatrixService via the javascript-API.

The correct documentation you'll find at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix