# Specify API Key For Google Matrix API Javascript To Retrieve Usage

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, matrix

i am using google matrix API successfully to retrieve the time and distance for location a to location b.

```
var origins = [Task.getItem("Y") + "," + Task.getItem("X")];
            var destinations = [LAT + "," + LNG];

            var distanceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            var distanceRequest = {
                origins: origins,
                destinations: destinations,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            };
            distanceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix(distanceRequest, function(response, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Error was: ' + status);
                } else {
                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                    //debugger;
                    if (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance != null) {
                        totalDistance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
                        totalTime = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
                        ratioPerOneMeter = totalDistance / totalTime;
                        PRDifference = 0;

                        updateDistanceAndTime();

                    } else {
                        alert("The Distance And Time Cannot Be Calculated");
                    }
                }
            });
```

What I want to do is add the API key but I don't know how. I did add in the API key:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={KEY}&v=3.exp">
```

as stated here: 
[Using a Google Apps API key with Distance Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899484/using-a-google-apps-api-key-with-distance-matrix)

but I think this is just for the map and not for the matrix API. Can someone inform me if this is enough.

Comment: Just remove this `key={KEY}&` or obtain a developer key from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?pli=1)

Comment: i have a developer key and i wrote it... but i just wrote the link like that here. my question is if this is enough or should i specify the key also for the matrix api somewhere else

Comment: Not required to specify api somewhere else if JavaScript is using api key somewhere it will reference this one you added in the url as `key`;

Comment: i dont think thats true because in the developer console, Google Maps Distance Matrix API usage shows 0 requests though i did request... while Google Maps JavaScript API does show requests.

Comment: Did you enable `Google Maps Distance Matrix API` for the project?

Comment: The API console report for the Distance Matrix API is for the web service, not calls made from the Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Comment: @geocodezip when i call the DistanceMatrixService and retrieving the road duration and distance, arent i calling the distance matrix API?.... if not then how can i determine the limitations and how much requests are being done per day

Comment: Not if you are doing it from inside the Google Maps Javascript API v3, that quota is different from the quota reported in the API/developer console for the Google Maps Distance Matrix API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps Distance Matrix Service in the Google Maps Javascript API uses the key provided in the API include.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={KEY}">
```

That usage is not tracked separately in the developer console.  The usage tracked under "Google Maps Distance Matrix API" is the usage of the Web Service only.

Comment: so the usage is unlimited or what in this case for the matrix API?!

Comment: None of Google's APIs has "unlimited" usage.  There is a quota and a rate limit built into the API, typically it is a per client quota/rate limit, but some of the services require or are limited using the key.

Comment: i do understand this but what im not understanding is how can i log how much usage is my web app consuming for this particular API. thanks anyway

Comment: That is a different question from the one you asked.  You can write code to log calls to the DistanceMatrix from your app.